# Consider the space $\Bbb R_l$ that is $\Bbb R$ with the lower limit topology. Show that $\Bbb R_l$ is Lindelöf.

Tags: general-topology, sorgenfrey-line, lindelof-spaces

> Consider the space $\Bbb R_l$ that is $\Bbb R$ with the lower limit topology. Show that $\Bbb R_l$ is Lindelöf.

I am trying to understand a proof, but I don't know why the result implies that $\Bbb R_l$ is Lindelöf. It goes like this.

Let $\mathcal{A}=\{U_j \mid j \in J\}$ be an open cover of $\Bbb R_l$. Let $V_j=\operatorname{int}(U_j)$ in the standard topology of $\Bbb R$ and $V=\bigcup\{V_j \mid j \in J\}$. Since $V$ is second-countable and therefore Lindelöf in the standard topology of $\Bbb R$ we know that there exists countable $K\subset J$ such that $V=\bigcup\{V_j \mid j \in K\}$ covers $\Bbb R$.

Showing that $A= \Bbb R \setminus V$ is countable will imply the result.

The proof ends here and I cannot figure out why showing $A= \Bbb R \setminus V$ will imply that $\Bbb R_l$ is Lindelöf?

Comment: $\Bbb{R}\setminus V$ countable implies we can select countably many open sets from $\mathcal{A}$ to cover all those points in $\Bbb{R}$ which are not covered by $\{U_j :j\in K\}$ .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Sorgenfrey line ($\mathbb R$ endowed with the lower limit topology $\tau_l$) is Lindelöf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312955/the-sorgenfrey-line-mathbb-r-endowed-with-the-lower-limit-topology-tau-l)

Comment: Also see  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3183987/977780